# Webcomic with a mermaid and a bird legged android?

Tags: story-identification, comics, webcomics, androids, mermaids

Webcomic with a mermaid and a bird legged android?

I watched a while back a first part youtube video about a webcomic with a mermaid and a bird legged android. It was maybe 5 years old and maybe was totally just a short 3 part videos. One of the comments said that the webcomics already ended. I just cant remember its name.

The A plot that a mermaid and her two merman(?) friends swimming in the sea, then she goes into a tunnel and stuck in. They try to calm her down, but she swimming up in the sewer into the city is river. We see that the two male worries for her and speaking what to do, because she was younger or something. She was very different from the typical mermaid, she dont have hair or eye pupils, just blank white eyes. She dont have a tradicional mermaid fish tail, more like an eel/moray eel tail and green colors. She has very long lower body, has transparent membranes and some kind of phlegm. Maybe she can dissolve her lower body/tail, and have legs or something.

The B plot that a male android waking up in a beach side house, with maybe cables in his head. Then maybe a girl commenting to a guy that why he replaced his legs with bird like legs. The android is not liking it either and try to walk. They joking around a bit and sent him to the city for something. Where he maybe see the mermaid in the river and they start talking. He was a tall, pale skined maybe black haired human like android with bird legs.

The drawing and the characters are wasnt childish or anime like. I hope somebody can help me find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Thermohalia](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57008/most-interesting-comics-week).

> Heather Penn’s webcomic Thermohalia joyfully combines mermaids, robots, and teen aliens. With about 3 chapters posted to date (some are on her website, but she seems to have moved to updating the comic more regularly on Tapastic.com), the story follows a young mermaid (or maybe part-girl/part-eel) named Coi who ventures into a city above the water where she meets a part-human/part-bird robot named Heghera.

[image]

Comment: For the record, I found this by googling "Webcomic with a mermaid and a bird legged android"

Comment: XD Yeah, this is it! Thank you!

Comment: I went to the link you provided that summarizes the webcomic, but every link I tried in that article to teh actual webcomic itself appears to be dead for me.  [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/comics/comments/2yuk8p/thermohalia_someone_here_has_a_backup_saved_xpost/) link was asking if anyone saved it, and points to some links on imgur

Comment: I missed on the Reddit post that it had an official link to the WebComic - [Thermohalia](https://heatpenn.itch.io/thermohalia)

Comment: @PeterM - The entire thing is available on Imgur but I'm not posting copyright-infringing links here.

Comment: Yeah, its really sad that the creator stopped Thermohalia, not a really memorable name tho. It was very interesting with unique character design and world building. They tried to reboot it with Protean Sea, but I more liked her original design. Unfortunately it seems they stopped updating a while ago. Its really such a waste, it had soo much potential to be a really great story. :(

Comment: A general reminder that the Way Back Machine exists, and can absolutely recover a webcomic thats been shut down if you know the URL.